# Grab content of a div and insert in another one

Tags: jquery

Hi guys i'm trying to create a "zen view" mode for my blog articles, so i want to grab only the content of the #single div (only the article content no header or siderbar etc...) and put it into another div called #zen-view, note that i use **WordPress.**

So i try to make this code for now:

```
<button class="zen">Read in Zen mode</button>   // when clicked display #zen-view div
<div id="zen-view">  // initialy the css of that div is set to display:none
<p id="zen-content"></p>   // the tag where the contet of the #single div will be load
<button class="close" href="#">Close Zen mode</button>   // when clicked close zen-view div
</div>
```

and here is the jquery

```
$(function() {

     $('.zen').click( function() {
            $('#zen-view').show();
            ... how can i grab the content of #single div and put into #zen-content div? ...
        });
     $('.close').click( function() {
            $('#zen-view').hide();

        });
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why are you using classes ('zen' and 'close') to do the job of ids?

Answer (score 1):

> how can i grab the content of #single div and put into #zen-content div?

```
$('#zen-content').html($('#zen-content').html());
```

If you don't want to override `#zen-content` content:

```
$('#zen-content').append($('#single').html());
```

Or with plain js:

```
document.getElementById('zen-content').innerHTML += $('#single').html();
```

Comment: ++1 and now I will type 30 chars! Who is -1-ing (Downvoting) :)) this?

Comment: @Tats_innit. I guess someone who reached the cap already and doesn't mind to lose one point.... `:)`

Comment: lolz :P and as soon I typed my previous comment my +1 was gone LMAO <love this @ times> its like a wolverine game if you have played one in tech camps or uni. :P (Poor villagers always have low hand) :)

Comment: An alternative to your last line is `$('#zen-content').append($('#single').html());` (note also that you're currently setting '#zen-content' to show its own content instead of taking content from '#single').

Comment: @nnnnnn. Oops.. better than [my previous typo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11133949/601179) LOL.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#zen-content').html($('#single').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/QRv6d/11/

Good read: http://api.jquery.com/html/

**code**

```
$(function() {

     $('.zen').click( function() {
            $('#zen-view').show();
             $('#zen-content').html($('#single').html());
            //... how can i grab the content of #single div and put into #zen-content div? ...
        });
     $('.close').click( function() {
            $('#zen-view').hide();

        });
    });​
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as copying the HTML code as a string into another element as suggested by the previous answers, you can clone the actual DOM tree, e.g.:

```
$('#zen').append($('#single').children().clone());
```

Against the following HTML:

```
<div id="single">
    <div class="innerContent">Some content over here <i>with markup</i></div>    
</div>
<div id="zen" />
```

This, however, would require you to enclose the content of a blog post into another div, because without a call to `children()` you would clone the original blog post's div instead of only the contents.

See also a running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/N3wFH/ .